# Is there a windows 7 driver for ICH10R that supports >2TB drives?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, intel-core-i7, chipset

The ICH10R controller on my ASUS P6T SE board does support drives larger than 2 TB, however, the windows driver I can find doesn't. I am trying to use a 4 TB HDD, I am **not** trying to boot from that drive.

- The 4 TB drive functions just fine if I boot a Linux distribution
- Windows 7 disk management displays that the drive has a capacity below 2 TB
- Intel Matrix Storage Console displays the drive capacity correctly
- The driver version is 8.9.0.1023, which, to my knowledge, is the newest available

The controller is set to "AHCI", if i set it to "RAID" Windows doesn't boot (Windows boot screen shows up, computer resets). I assume I could re-install Windows in "RAID" mode and would manage to get a bootable system, however, I'd really like to continue using the Windows installation as it is. Also, I guess the problem would persist in "RAID" mode.

Again, I don't need to boot from the 4 TB drive, so any bios issues aren't really relevant. The bios is up to date though and also correctly recognises the drive size. Just the Windows controller driver doesn't. I just wonder if I missed anything and there is a newer driver that I can use, since apparently the Linux driver supports larger drives (and to my knowledge, Intel contributes these drivers to the kernel).

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? I have exactly the same one.

Comment: @Oliver TBH I don't remember. I assume not, otherwise I might have posted an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the partition table type from [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) to [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) so Windows will see the full capacity.

1. Open command prompt in the Start menu.
2. Type *diskpart* in the command prompt and press enter.
3. Type *list disk* and press enter.
4. Type *select disk #* ( #-the disk you want to convert) and press enter.
5. Type *detail disk* and press enter.  It will give you a list of all the volumes on the selected disk.  If you have no volumes listed, then you can go to step 9.
6. Type *select volume #* and press enter.
7. Type *delete volume* and press enter.
8. Repeat steps 6 and 7 for each volume listed in step 5 until you have deleted all volumes.
9. Type *select disk #* and press enter.
10. Type *convert gpt* and press enter
11. Type *exit* and press enter

[Source for steps and more info](http://www.disk-partition.com/blog/3tb-external-hard-drive-only-showing-2tb-in-disk-management/)

Comment: The disk has no partition scheme, neither MBR nor GPT. The entire **device** size is reported to be below 2 TB. I can create a GPT partition table with the management console, however, that does not change the reported device size.